Super key stopped working on Debian 12 and Gnome
I have Debian 12, the stable version, and Gnome. After installing some web browsers, my super key stopped working...
Somebody had the same problem apparently, but his solution did not work out for me:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663758/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best
Edit: As per ChanganAuto's request, my only actions are the ones in the post I quote, that is trying all the F keys. Moreover, my hotkey finally spontaneously worked again... but stopped again...

Your linked Q&A as a few different answers. Have you tried all of them? If so, please [edit] the question to reflect all you've tried already.
